# EntityFramework Core: Get changes occured in entity and related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to get changes occured in an entity and related datas attached to it.

I know how to get the property names that have changed in one entity:

```
 dbContext.Entry(entity).Properties.Where(x => x.IsModified).Select(x => x.Metadata.Name).ToList();
```

How to do the same for related data in navigation properties ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on this [article (Entity Change Tracking using DbContext in Entity Framework 6)](https://exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/), you should override `SaveChanges()` method to track entity changes and its related entities.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Actually, You should change the above code to the following sample:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
    {
        var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
        var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change);

        foreach(var prop in change.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            var originalValue = change.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
            var currentValue = change.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
            if (originalValue != currentValue) //Only create a log if the value changes
            {
                //Create the Change Log
            }
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You ar emaking a call to a method you have not defined in the answer `GetPrimaryKeyValue()`. Also note that `OriginalValues` and `CurrentValeus` will *not* include navigations if if those are filled in on the entity itself.